# Angular validation triggers for textbox has a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a survey with AngularJS and there is a textbox at the beginning.

```
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" 
placeholder="Name" value="{{answers.name}}" required />
```

And there are next and previous buttons.

When I click first next and then previous, this textbox still holds the value I entered.

If I click next again, required is triggered although textbox is not empty. Here is the message I display.

```
<p ng-hide="this.isValid" class="err">Please fill the form.</p>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is "this" in ng-hide?

Comment: Form I suppose, it still works without 'this'.

Comment: Is there a class .ng-dirty or .ng-pristine on the filled textbox after clicking previous?

Comment: ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched, these are the classes.

Comment: As far as I know ng-pristine is only set to empty inputs which are not touched. Maybe you should try to redefine the value after clicking previous.